Adding additional steps to a SAS DO loop based on the iteration value
I using a DO loop to run Proc SQL queries iterating through a list of variables. I am wondering if there is a way to add steps to that DO loop when i = only certain variables, and skip those steps for the rest? ABRV and PLAN_IDS are combinations of strings from the variable list that I am looping through. The reason I would like to do this as part of the same macro is the program runs on a schedule through an automation system. I want to create 7 tables, 6 using only the first query and a 7th that uses the variables for i=6 only (in bold)
%macro Create_Tables;
%do i =1 %to 6;
proc sql;
create table BASELINE_UTILIZATION&&ABRV&i as
select 
t1.PLAN_NAME,
t1.STATE_CODE,
t1."PLAN ID",
SUM(t1.Rx#) As BL_Rx,
SUM(t1.Qty) As BL_Qty
from report_table_1 t1 
where t1.State_Code = &&ABRV&i
AND t1."PLAN ID" IN (&&PLAN_IDS&i)
AND t1.Paiddate in ('202401') 
GROUP BY t1.PLAN_NAME, t1.STATE_CODE, t1."PLAN ID"
);
**IF i=6 THEN
create table EXTRA_UTILIZATION&&ABRV&i
proc sql;
select
t1.PLAN_NAME,
t1.STATE_CODE,
t1."PLAN ID",
SUM(t1.Rx#) *4 As BL_Rx_extra,
SUM(t1.Qty) *4 As BL_Qty_extra
from report_table_1 t1
where t1.State_Code = &&ABRV&i
AND t1."PLAN ID" IN (&&PLAN_IDS&i)
AND t1.Paiddate in ('202401') 
GROUP BY t1.PLAN_NAME, t1.STATE_CODE, t1."PLAN ID"
);**
%end;
%mend Create_Tables;
%Create_Tables


Note: You are using a macro %DO loop.  Not an actual data step DO loop.

With Tom's help, this is the basic structure of the code I was able to run correctly:
%macro Create_Tables;
%do i=1 to i=6;
* Proc SQL Query 1
%if &i=6 %then% do;
* Proc SQL Query 2
%end;
%end;
%mend Create_Tables;
%Create_Tables;


To conditionally generate code in a macro using a %IF statement.
Sounds like you just want to use something like:
%if &I = 6 %then %do;
* some statements here;
%end;
%else %do;
* other statements here;
%end;


Thank you, this feels like it has gotten me closer! I am trying to add the %if i=6 %then %do; statement within the same %create_tables macro but can't seem to get the syntax right. The way I have it now, the program is running successfully but ignoring the i=6 statement and not creating the EXTRA_UTILIZATION&&ABRV&i table at all

The letter I can never equal the digit 6.  The value of the macro variable I which is referenced with &I might possibly be the same as the digit 6.
